# Implementation of LIFO in converting comma separated row values into separate row values

Tags: r

I have a `data frame` where individual row values are comma separated, I wanted to separate the comma values into individual row values. So using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525811/how-to-separate-comma-separated-values-in-r-in-a-new-row) SO post is was able to achieve in converting comma separated string values in individual rows, but, It replaces first value if the string as the first values if the row and I wanted to have the inverse of this, i.e `First string value is the last row value`.

```
# create data 
library(tidyverse)
d <- data_frame(
  col1 = c("1,2,3")
)
```

`Dataframe`

```
    # # A tibble: 3 x 2
#              col1
#              <chr>
# 1            1,2,3


# tidy data
separate_rows(d, col1, convert = TRUE)
```

`Current Output`

```
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#     col1
#    <int>
#      1
#      2
#      3
```

`Desired Output`

```
# tidy data
separate_rows(d, col1, convert = TRUE)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#     col1
#    <int>
#      3
#      2
#      1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split the column on commas, reverse the vector, construct a data frame.

Sample data:

```
> d = data.frame(col1=c("23,34,99","9,3,2"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> d
      col1
1 23,34,99
2    9,3,2
```

Do:

```
> data.frame(col1=do.call(c,lapply(strsplit(d$col1,","),rev)))
  col1
1   99
2   34
3   23
4    2
5    3
6    9
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Works Perfect

Answer (score 2):

We can invert the dataframe and select the indices in reverse order using `slice`

```
library(tidyverse)
separate_rows(d, col1, convert = TRUE) %>%
   slice(n():1)

#   col1
#   <int>
#1     3
#2     2
#3     1
```

---

For multiple rows, taking @Spacedman's example

```
d = data.frame(col1=c("23,34,99","9,3,2"),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

The above solution would give

```
separate_rows(d, col1, convert = TRUE) %>%
     slice(n():1)
# A tibble: 6 x 1
     col1
    <int>
#1     2
#2     3
#3     9
#4    99
#5    34
#6    23
```

However, in case if OP needs to reverse the string for each row seperately we can create a `group` column with `row_number` and then reverse the string for each row separately as suggested by @Sotos

```
d %>%
  mutate(group = row_number()) %>%
  separate_rows(col1, convert = TRUE) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  slice(n():1) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)


# A tibble: 6 x 1
#   col1
#  <int>
#1    99
#2    34
#3    23
#4     2
#5     3
#6     9
```

Comment: Nice one! Did not know you could do  that (though it makes sense) :)

Comment: @Sotos yes, although I am not sure what would OP's expected output in case of multiple observations.

Comment: However If you try it with multiple rows it fails (try it on Spacedman's example)

Comment: OP has not clarified what is their expected output in case of multiple rows. However, this still satisfies the LIFO property which OP has mentioned. I would wait for OP to clarify.

Comment: I guess you could create rownumbers before separating and arrange after to get the strings in the correct order (assuming that is required by OP)

Comment: @RonakShah Yes I apologize for not mentioning about multiple observations, Your solution works well by implementing `LIFO` for one observation but does not work for multiple observation.

Comment: @ANmike updated the solution for multiple observations.

Comment: This is about four times slower than the base R method using `strsplit` and `rev`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stri_reverse` from `stringi` package and reverse the string prior to separating, i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>% 
 mutate(col1 = stringi::stri_reverse(col1)) %>% 
 separate_rows(col1)
```

which gives

> ```
> A tibble: 3 x 1
>   col1 
>   <chr>
> 1 3    
> 2 2    
> 3 1
> ```

Comment: Your solution works well too but it reverses the individual elements of the string along with reversing the string.